# not able to convert int[] to int?[]

Tags: c#, linq

Below is code implementation I am not able to convert int[] to int?[]

```
days = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Days) ? 
Days.Split("|").Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray() : null
```

How to resolve it in a single line

Comment: You probably meant succinct readable code, not one-liner. This is not code golf...

Comment: I'm getting `cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'`

Answer (score 1):

Cast the Convert.ToInt32 result to int?:

```
days = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Days) ? 
Days.Split("|").Select(x => (int?)Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray() : null
```